# Metacharacters when in a character class (`[]`)

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

My understanding of Java Regex is this.  There are two sets of metacharacters:

- Used in a regular expression outside of a character classes (enclosed within `[]`): `<([{\\^-=$!|]})?*+.>`
- Used within a character classes: `\][-&^`

If we want a certain character (e.g. hyphen `-`) to be matched literally in a character class, we will have to escape it by a backslash (`\`).

This view is supported by the following description in [Java Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

> **Character Classes**
>   Character classes may appear within other character
>   classes, and may be composed by the union operator (implicit) and the
>   intersection operator (&&). The union operator denotes a class that
>   contains every character that is in at least one of its operand
>   classes. The intersection operator denotes a class that contains every
>   character that is in both of its operand classes.
>
> The precedence of character-class operators is as follows, from
>   highest to lowest:
>
> 1. Literal escape      \x
> 2. Grouping    [...]
> 3. Range   a-z
> 4. Union   [a-e][i-u]
> 5. Intersection    [a-z&&[aeiou]]
>
> Note that a
>   different set of metacharacters are in effect inside a character class
>   than outside a character class.

Is this a correct understanding?

What surprised me is that, to escape the second set in a character class, apart from using backslash, we also seem to be able to use `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote()`.  I thought the method is intended for the first set of metacharacters only.

**Test Program**

The following test program illustrates that both `Pattern.quote()` and `\` (as well as `\Q` and `\E`) can be used to quote hyphen in a character class:

```
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.TestName;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    @Rule
    public TestName testName = new TestName();

    @Test
    public void testHyphenCharClassByPatternQuote() {
        String regex = "[" + Pattern.quote("-") + "]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String[] tests = {
            "-"
            , "a"
        };
        for (String test : tests) {
            System.out.println(testName.getMethodName() + " matching " + test + ":" + p.matcher(test).matches());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testHyphenCharClassByBackSlash() {
        String regex = "[\\-]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String[] tests = {
            "-"
            , "a"
        };
        for (String test : tests) {
            System.out.println(testName.getMethodName() + " matching " + test + ":" + p.matcher(test).matches());
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testHyphenCharClassByQE() {
        String regex = "[\\Q-\\E]";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
        String[] tests = {
            "-"
            , "a"
        };
        for (String test : tests) {
            System.out.println(testName.getMethodName() + " matching " + test + ":" + p.matcher(test).matches());
        }
    }

}
```

**Test output**

```
testHyphenCharClassByQE matching -:true
testHyphenCharClassByQE matching a:false
testHyphenCharClassByBackSlash matching -:true
testHyphenCharClassByBackSlash matching a:false
testHyphenCharClassByPatternQuote matching -:true
testHyphenCharClassByPatternQuote matching a:false
```

Comment: When considering escaping note the placement of "`-`" has special meaning in a character class, where "`[-]`" means "The literal character “-”." and "`[a-z-]`" means "Match a single character present in the list below «`[a-z-]`», A character in the range between “`a`” and “`z`” (case sensitive) «`a-z`», The literal character “`-`” «`-`»".

Answer (score 1):

You are basically correct, but the `pattern.quote()` method works as expected. What seems to confuse you is the nature of the hyphen in a character class range.

The [Pattern class doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) lists the following escape modifiers under the **Quotation**
 section:

> `\`  Nothing, but quotes the following character
>   `\Q` Nothing, but quotes all characters until `\E`
>   `\E` Nothing, but ends quoting started by `\Q`

All `pattern.quote` does is to wrap input with `\Q` and `\E` to produce a literalized string.

Citing from the Java doc on `quote`

> Returns a literal pattern String for the specified String.   This
>   method produces a String that can be used to create a Pattern that
>   would match the string s as if it were a literal pattern.
>   Metacharacters or escape sequences in the input sequence will be given
>   no special meaning.

<sub>Technically, everything from a `\Q` (exclusive) to the next `\E` (exclusive), which may include any number of `\Q` sequences, is literalized.</sub>

When you escape/quote the hypen in a character class (or put it at the end) it will lose its special meaning, i.e. define a range, and it just becomes a literal hyphen as demonstrated by yourself:

```
String regex = "[a\\-z]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
String[] tests = {
    "-"
    , "a"
    , "b"
    , "z"
};
for (String test : tests) {
    System.out.println(" matching " + test + ":" + p.matcher(test).matches());
}
```

Outputs:

```
 matching -:true
 matching a:true
 matching b:false
 matching z:true
```

Comment: Thanks!  I was surprise to see that `\Q` and `\E` (and hence also `Pattern.quote()`) would be useful to quote metacharacter **in a character class**.  I was thinking that it applies only to outside of a character class.

Answer (score 0):

I can now confirm that `\Q` and `\E` (and hence also `Pattern.quote()`) would be useful to quote metacharacter **in a character class**, in addition to **outside** a character class. I was thinking that it applies only to outside of a character class, and that understanding was wrong.  I wish the documentation states this more clearly.